# How do I use Excel to count the times a string appears in other sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet that contains 10 sheets with data about facility checklists.

I am wanting to create an overview sheet that looks through all of the other sheets can counts the number of times the string "N" appear in column B5.

I have tried `=VLOOKUP("N", September 2015!$B$5:June 2016!$B$5, 2)` but I am unable to get into look through the other sheets.

The sheets are named with the months name and the year (i.e September 2015).

Also I would prefer not to use macros or VBA.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You should use COUNTIF function. It can work on single cell like B5 or range of cells or even entire column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not many Excel functions support 3D references, i.e. references across several sheets.

The easiest way might be to create a Countif() formula in each sheet and then use a Sum with a 3D reference to total the Countif results.

So, in each sheet, identify a cell, say Z1 (or a cell of your choice, as long as it's the same cell address in each sheet). Click the sheet tab of the first sheet. Shift-click the sheet tab of the last sheet. Now click Z1 and enter a formula like

=COUNTIF(A1:Y100,"N")

- Now, on your summary sheet type =Sum(
- Click the first sheet, then click on Z1
- Shift click on the last sheet, close the bracket and enter the formula. The formula will look like

=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet10!Z1)

... where Sheet1 and Sheet10 should reflect your sheet names.

Answer (score 0):

On your overview sheet select the desired cell and string countif formulas for each sheet with +.  Ex.: `=COUNTIF(sheet1!$A$1:$G$10,"value")+COUNTIf(sheet2!$A$1:$G$10,"value")` and so on... you may have to put each `COUNTIF` inside a `NUMBERVALUE()`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not required on a frequent basis, you might try to save the whole spreadsheet as pdf and then ctrl+f.